# Shell script file existence test fails for broken symbolic link

Tags: shell, sh, symlink

This Bourne shell script fails to detect the existence of a broken symbolic link. It returns `false` and doesn't `echo` yet `/usr/bin/firefox.real` is a file that exists but as a broken symbolic link. Why?

```
FIREFOX="/usr/bin/firefox.real"

[ -e "$FIREFOX" ] && echo "exists"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that internally, bash will call fstat(), not lstat() when you test with -e, so it checks the file itself, not the symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks! This answer hits the nail on the head. Is it specific to `bash` or does it apply to the Bourne shell (my shell of interest) as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use `-h` to check for existence of a link (even broken):

```
[ -h "$FIREFOX" ] && echo "exists"
```

As per `man test`:

```
  -h FILE
          FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. While it provides the correct way to test for links, it doesn't quite answer the question I raised.